# SwiftUI ContextMenu with Submenu

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am developing a macOS app in SwiftUI. I am using `.contextMenu` modifier inside my List. It all works fine, however I am trying to make a submenu.

Usually I am just using buttons, I am not trying to make a hierarchy / or a submenu. It is possible and being used in many Apple default apps. I just not sure how to create that menu. That's the code I am currently using

```
.contextMenu {
    Button(action: {
    })
    {
        Text("Button")
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the default Calendar app, with a sub menu.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `Menu` for nested menu hierarchies:

```
.contextMenu {
    Menu("Nested Root") {
        Button("Nested #1") {}
        Button("Nested #2") {}
        Button("Nested #3") {}
    }
    Button("Not Nested") { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I need a solution for macOS 10+ and menu is only available from 11+. However, I think there is no other solution yet. I will accept that answer

Comment: I'm on iOS 13 we don't have a Menu here